# Secure MySQL backup cron job – my.cnf is not being read

Tags: mysql, security, cron, freebsd

I have tried to make backup cron job on my webserver running FreeBSD. Currently it looks something like this:

> `/usr/local/bin/mysqldump --opt --single-transaction --comments --dump-date  --no-autocommit --all-databases --result-file=/var/backups/mysql/all.sql`

It works fine when I run it as root (since root has a `.my.cnf` with the username and password used to connect, but when the job is run by cron, the `my.cnf` file is not read.

Is there any way around that without having to put username and password into the command itself (since that's kinda insecure)?

Strangely, I have the same setup with PostgreSQL and a `.pgpass` file, and that works like a charm.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the [`--defaults-extra-file`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/option-files.html) option to tell it where to find the `.my.cnf` file (assuming it's readable by whichever user is running `mysqldump`.

Comment: Ah, yes. How did I miss that. I'll just stick that in to my nightly job. Look forward to getting the message that it when I'm sleeping :)

Comment: actually, it wasn't that easy to find in the MySQL online docs.  None of the individual programs mention that option in their manpages.

Comment: `mysql: unknown variable 'defaults-extra-file=~/.my.cnf`

Comment: @Alnitak, Apparently, only in the most recent release. It's not available in any version of MySQL I'm currently using...

Comment: @Cerin I've no idea what you're on about.  Try clicking on the link in my answer which goes to the MySQL 5.0 documentation for that option.

Comment: @Alnitak, That's nice. It's still an invalid command line option in MySQL 5.5. `man mysql|grep -i default` shows no --defaults-extra-file option. Where do you think my error came from?

Comment: @Cerin replace the 5.0 in my link with 5.5 (here - I've done it for you - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/option-files.html) - the option is still there in the docs.

Comment: @Alnitak, And if you actually tried running with that option with your client, you'd see it doesn't work. Try being more empirical and less snarky. Did you even read that link? It says "most" programs, not "all", such as the mysql client the OP is using.

Comment: @Cerin, I think it's may because of mysql client require this option is first argument, try mysql -help | grep default you'll found this option. Actually I've got the same error, and fixed it by put that option in first argument.

Answer (score 2):

Thats weird actually cron should read the .my.cnf. How do you run the cronjob in /etc/crontab or crontab -e? You could try using [AutoMySQLBackup](http://sourceforge.net/projects/automysqlbackup/) which is a small shell script using mysqldump.

Comment: Well, actually it is not run directly from cron, but by FreeBSDs `periodic` system. It's actually a script file in /usr/local/etc/periodic/daily

The periodic cron jobs are run through `/etc/cron` like this:
> `1       3       *       *       *       root    periodic daily`

Comment: Oh, Markdown is not enabled in the comments. Hope its legible anyways :)

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this as well.

It appears that MySQL is hardcoded to look for '~/.my.cnf', instead of something like '$HOME/.my.cnf'.

On FreeBSD, cronjobs called from /etc/crontab will ignore the tilde '~' character, and therefore will ignore a value like ~/.my.cnf

In fact, the following doesn't work for me at all:

mysql --defaults-extra-file=~/.my.cnf

However, using a $HOME variable does work:

HOME=/home/admin
mysql --defaults-extra-file=$HOME/.my.cnf

As an alternative, my cronjob will work if I move it from /etc/crontab to /var/cron/tabs/root (Using 'crontab -e' as root).

Answer (score 0):

On FreeBSD you can add the following:

```
security.bsd.see_other_uids=0
```

To /etc/sysctl.conf and reboot, or use

```
sysctl security.bsd.see_other_uids=0
```

To set the sysctl value.

Now users other than root are only able to view their own processes. So putting the password in the command line is less risky.

Also, how are running crontab? Did you add it to the root users crontab by using crontab -e -u root, or did you add it to /etc/crontab?

Verify that the right permissions are set on the .my.cnf as well as what environment variables are set by crontab as that may cause it to look in a different location than your home directory (which for root on FreeBSD is /root).